# Android Studio - Open url

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new in android studio. I have a website that I want to create an android app for it.

My question is simple, just to help me to start, I want a code that opens my website url in the APP (not in the browser) "www.mywebsite.com" when the user opens my app.

Can someone provide me that code?

thank you very much!

Comment: Google about `webview` and you'll find all those what you need..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Add below code in your Activity:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.mywebsite.com");
```

Comment: oh, thank you very much! I will try it now! thank you